# Command Line Rename Korean File Name

Tags: command-line

I've this file I just downloaded with the name `최고다 이순신.E39.130720.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi`, and I've the subtitle file `You're.the.Best.Lee.Soon.Shin.E39.130720.HDTV.H264.720p-KOR.srt`.

How can I rename the video file (in command line) with the same name as the subtitle file?

`You're.the.Best.Lee.Soon.Shin.E39.130720.HDTV.H264.720p-KOR.avi`

`You're.the.Best.Lee.Soon.Shin.E39.130720.HDTV.H264.720p-KOR.srt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone has a better solution, but here's what I would do:

1. In the directory in which the file resides, do `ls -li` and get the inode number of the file -- it shall be listed in the first column of the output.
2. In the same directory, execute: `find . -maxdepth 1 -inum 1234567 -exec mv {} new-name-of-file.blah \;` substituting the `1234567` for your file's inode number, and the `new-name-of-file.blah` with the new name that you want to give.

Note that the `\;` part of the `find` command is necessary to signify the end of the command.